# Иероглифы в PostgresQL

Tags: postgresql, кодировка, utf-8

Установил postgres 14.5, при запуске sql shell частично выводит текст кракозябрами.
Как мне это исправить?
В настройках стоит Lucida Console 14.
Пробовал делать как в похожих проблемах, не помогает.

Система Windows 10
PostgreSQL 14.5

[image: скриншот postgresql shell]

Comment: Вот прямо на скриншоте есть вполне осмысленный совет.

Comment: @Akina выполнил: postgres=# set client_encoding='WIN866';
результат тоже
выполнил postgres=# set client_encoding='win1251';
результат тоже

Comment: *В настройках стоит Lucida Console 14* Вот чисто для проверки - поставь Terminal...

Comment: Все сделал, странно, вчера весь день убил.. помогло chcp 1251..

Answer (score 1):

Помогло:

```
chcp 1251

psql -d ВАШАБАЗА -U ВАШЛОГИН

set client_encoding='win1251';
```

Ну и соответственно шрифт Lucida Console 14 уже стоял.
Спасибо!